# Group by Pandas data and keep values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe looking like this

```
| | Sentence | Text  | Classes 
 0     1        a      Object
 1     1        a      Object
 2     1        a      Object
 3     1        a      Object
 4     1      school   Depart
 5     1        is     Verb
 6     1      closed   O
 .
 .
 .    60         a     Verb
```

And I want to group by the text by most frequent type of class, so it ends like this:

```
| | Sentence | Text  | Classes 
 0     1        a      Object
 1     1        is     Verb
 2     1      school   Depart
 3     1      closed   O
```

It is very important that the sentence order is kept when grouping the data, and when I try myself with the following code, it does group the data, but removes entries with only one occurrence:

```
def md(s):
c = Counter(s)
return c.most_common(1)[0][0]
df_final = df.groupby(['Sentence','Text']).Classes.agg(md)
```

Comment: looks like you could just `drop_duplicates`

Comment: @sammywemmy how would you propose that? I'll still need to distinguish between most frequent words to know which one to delete

Comment: maybe change your data to reflect better what you have in mind, because if you use ``df.drop_duplicates()``, it gives out your current output

Comment: @sammywemmy Your solution was not what I had in mind, but it actually does the trick. I will be using it for a NER tagging and tried to avoid duplicate words. With your solution, I currently have two entries for 'a' as class = Object and 'a' as class = Verb, while I was thinking to only have one unique word per sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your function is not removing entries with a single occurrence (i.e. number of records for the group).

If you want to maintain the order of words within the sentence, you can add `as_index=False, sort=False` as options to the `groupby`, if that is what you mean by "sentence order is kept when grouping the data".

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
from collections import Counter

data = [['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'],
        ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'school', 'is', 'closed'],
        ['Object', 'Object', 'Object', 'Object', 'Depart', 'Verb', 'O']]

d = {'Sentence': data[0], 'Text': data[1], 'Classes': data[2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
def md(s):
    c = Counter(s)
    return c.most_common(1)[0][0]
df_final = df.groupby(['Sentence','Text'], as_index=False, sort=False).Classes.agg(md)
print(df_final)
```

Output:

```
  Sentence    Text Classes
0        1       a  Object
1        1  school  Depart
2        1      is    Verb
3        1  closed       O
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly it! I did not know that there were an implicit sorting when doing the group by. Thanks man :D